# Python/iptables: Original Destination IP

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, iptables

I'm trying to get original destination information for packets redirected with iptables (the ultimate goal is to redirect all network traffic to localhost while retaining the original destination ip).
I'm sending packets using the following code:

```
import socket  
HOST = '192.168.10.1'
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send(b'whatever')
s.close()
```

Then redirecting it with:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.10.1 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

And then receiving them with:

```
import socket
HOST = ''
PORT = 50007
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    s.listen(5)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Connected by', addr)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if(data):
        print(data)
conn.close()
```

I tried using something like

```
dst = conn.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.SO_ORIGINAL_DST, 16)
```

but this results in

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SO_ORIGINAL_DST'
```

Answer (score 3):

Some further reading and trying led me to my mistake. I got a little confused with various approaches I read about and lost track. The clue was in defining SO_ORIGINAL_DST (in this case for TCP).
This code (taken from [here](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/9ce2fa00f94c2f2e5c310abeb1a2907ae7e7a7b0/client.py)) does exactly what I want:

```
SO_ORIGINAL_DST = 80
sockaddr_in = conn.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP,
                              SO_ORIGINAL_DST, 16)
(proto, port, a, b, c, d) = struct.unpack('!HHBBBB', sockaddr_in[:8])
print('Original destination was: %d.%d.%d.%d:%d' % (a, b, c, d, port))
```